# how to detect version of browser and clear each browser history related to that domain only in javascript while login process

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, cross-browser

I am using a simple website,The problem is that if whenever i editing a website and making changes, i am not getting those changes immediately,to see those changes i have to clear my browser's cache.I need a way to tell my computer not to use the version of that file it downloaded previously, and to instead download a fresh copy of it. and also Sometimes i can hit the refresh button in my browser to download all the files from the website and not use cache, but if that does not work i can clear all of your browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

if your using chrome, develop in incognito mode

to do this just hit ctrl + shift + n on windows

or cmd + shift + n on mac

or click the hamburger icon in the top right of the browser and click new incognito window.

there is also a hamburger icon for firefox, select new private window

in safari, click file new private window

when you are in incognito / private mode it doesn't keep a cache or cookies

Answer (score 0):

On part was how to detect users browser you can this info from  `navigator.userAgent` it will also let you know about the os the user is using.
Second part of your question was answered above . If you are using chrome do a right click on anywhere n your site you will see a  Devtoolbox opens up after that click on the network tab and in there you have to check disable cache screen shot attached . you can use console to check the value of `navigator.userAgent`  '[image: screen shot]'